# jquery - refer to specific form

Tags: jquery, html

I have **number of forms** in my page.

How do I refer, in my code, only to the field in the specific submitted `form`?

```
                        <form class="modal-content" action="#">
                            <div class="modal-body">

                                <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">EMAIL</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
                                    <div class="help-block"></div>
                                    <!-- errors will go here -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-success submit">SEND<span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>


$(document).on('submit','form',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = {
        'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'password'          : $('input[name=password]').val(),
        'captcha'           : $('input[name=captcha]').val()
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get submitted form instance as `$(this)` and use `find()` to get fields inside the form submitted. See below code

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = {
        'email'             : $(this).find('input[name=email]').val(),
        'password'          : $(this).find('input[name=password]').val(),
        'captcha'           : $(this).find('input[name=captcha]').val()
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in Jquery :

```
$('#your_ID_form input[name=email]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each of your `form` an id and select it by id and use `this` to select specific values of selected `form`.

And use `find` to find (grand)child elements.

```
<form id="form1" class="modal-content" action="#">
...
</form>

$(document).on('submit','#form1',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = {
        'email'             : $(this).find('input[name=email]').val(),
        'password'          : $(this).find('input[name=password]').val(),
        'captcha'           : $(this).find('input[name=captcha]').val()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) or simply [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
    $(document).on('submit','form',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
        // if you need a json format:
        var jsonFormData = JSON.stringify(formData);
    });
```